# Why can't I upload files in a public Sftp?

Tags: sftp

I can only read my directory file but when even try to create a directory I get Permission access denied, Previously I was able to Read/write and Execute

and currently my account has `rwxr-xr-r` permission.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not connecting as the *owner* of the files, but using "public" (anonymous) access, you will see this behavior.

Comment: my directory has been already created, and i can also see my previous shared  files, it tendency that files are always shared with our Partner via their sftp server referred as Public server for external Users. now i cant share any More.